# Airflow Papermill operator: task externally skipped after 60 minutes

Tags: airflow, papermill

I am using Airflow in a Docker container. I run a DAG with multiple Jupyter notebooks. I have the following error everytime after 60 minutes:

```
[2021-08-22 09:15:15,650] {local_task_job.py:198} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to skipped. Terminating instance.
[2021-08-22 09:15:15,654] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 277
[2021-08-22 09:15:15,655] {taskinstance.py:1284} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-08-22 09:15:18,284] {taskinstance.py:1501} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

I tried to tweak the config file but could not find the good option to remove the 1 hour timeout.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is no timeout. When your DAG defines `dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)` and execution time exceeds 60 minutes then active task stops with message "*State of this instance has been externally set to skipped*" logged.